# MXD to PDF lines in PLSS are distorted in adobe PDF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, plss

[image][image]Using ArcGIS 10.7, what is causing my Section lines to blur or darken and thicken as you can see in this jpeg example of mine?  I have tried different transparency percentages, moved the feature around in the TOC, etc.  I created a new .mxd as this just happened after doing a map update.

This is a screenshot of a PDF.  The lines on the mxd are fine, and I have no idea how to correct this.  A PDF issue?

ADDENDUM - I opened it up in BLUEBEAM (image on left of the thick gray line is Bluebeam) The distortions are not as severe but locations of distorted lines have changed.
#BLUEBEAM #ADOBEpdf #MXD #ARCGIS10.7

Comment: Over the years I have seen similar quirks but I don't think I've ever been able to track their cause, and in all cases they have evaporated, presumably due to me making a change elsewhere in the MXD that put the PDF exporter back into kilter.  As with any ArcMap problem, I would test to see whether ArcGIS Pro resolves it.

Comment: yeesh! I should have tried this from the start.  I moved the PLSS layers to the top of the TOC.  It fixed it but still does NOT answer or provide why the Section files did what it did.

Answer (score 1):

Though it does not provide the answer to why the Section layer went all blurry, etc.  All I did was **MOVE** the **PLSS layer** to the **TOP of the TOC**.  That worked.